# Can't deploy project on firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, stackblitz

I have a project on stackbitlz. I am using Angular 10 and Firebase to build my website. When I deploy my site to a firebase server, I encounter a malfunction: on stackbitlz my site displays correctly, but after deployment the main page does not display on firebase hosting. I see the code from index.html and routing to the main page does not occur.

Help me, please!

my code: [github](https://github.com/markinaalya/testfirst)

release on firebase: [web site](https://my-first-d5b45.firebaseapp.com/?27353)

[angular.json](https://github.com/markinaalya/testfirst/blob/master/angular.json)

[Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/testfirst)

Comment: You have a js error message on console. Have you see it? 

`Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document`

Comment: Can you share with us your **firebase.json** ?

Comment: @JuanAntonio I don't have firebase.json, I have angular.json only. I edited my post.

Comment: And how are you deploying your project without it? Are you initialized your project with **firebase init**? You need to do it, specify your build folder to deploy, etc. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @JuanAntonio I deploy using the built-in functions of stackblitz

Comment: In this case maybe you have some missing file. You can also share your stackblitz project url to make a fork to try it. :)

Comment: @JuanAntonio see post, I added link

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic configuration that I use normally in any starter project on firebase:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Take a look if you need some config as like I do (you can skip ngsw-worker).